# Executing one command on multiple servers (VPS)

Tags: server, vps

I want to send one command to 12 different servers at the same time, i also am trying to use it with a discord bot, which uses commands (Not necessary).

Comment: Two options off the top of my head: first [Terminator](https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator) has a broadcast mode where your keystrokes go to multiple terminals (12 servers might be awkward though); second, Ansible is pretty simple for one command (`ansible -m shell -a 'cmd=...'` with servers in a file called 'hosts').

Comment: Ansible sounds good, can i only use it on linux or is there an download for it?

Comment: "[Windows is not supported for the control node.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html?extIdCarryOver=true&sc_cid=701f2000001OH6uAAG#prerequisites)" but it's easy to [install WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) and then [install Ansible on Ubuntu](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html?extIdCarryOver=true&sc_cid=701f2000001OH6uAAG#installing-ansible-on-ubuntu).